# Where to ask Careers questions, Stack Overflow meta or Stack Exchange Meta?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, jobs, meta, scope

There are a lot of Careers questions in SEMeta popping up. When Careers is placed as a branch of Stack Overflow, isn't Careers more affiliated with SO, instead of SEMeta? Aren't StackOverflow Careers questions site-based questions?

Why are Careers questions accepted in SEMeta when they are site-based?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack Exchange Meta is the place for posts regarding Careers.

Stack Overflow is not the only site on the network that Careers applies to - at the moment Server Fault is also applicable.

Though, it most cases it doesn't matter. Stack Exchange employees monitor both metas for Careers posts (though we would tend to migrate them here, to MSE).

Comment: So why are Careers placed under Stack Overflow?

Comment: Because that is where most of the CVs and jobs are. You may have noticed that Stack Overflow is almost  [2 orders of magnitude](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) (in traffic, questions, answers) and much larger than Server Fault in pretty much any other measurement. There is also much more brand recognition to Stack Overflow than even Stack Exchange (or any of the specifically branded sites).

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for clarifying it!