# Cyrillic letter and Russian names are mixed in a search result

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, jobs

I was searching for a job in Malmö, Sweden and got this response:

> [image: Screendump]

My Browser is FF 38.0.5 and I am living in Denmark and have not done anything to customize for Cyrillic letters or Russian language. Should the Cyrillic letters and Russian names be mixed in the search result?

Comment: Err stackoverflow careers should be on meta.so right?

Comment: @Uni no, MSE is the right meta for careers :)

Comment: @nicael If you say

Comment: @uni meta.so requires 5 points on SO; some questions about Careers are from people who don't participate on SO but have an ad on Careers.

Comment: @1999 so edit 2 things and get 5 rep

Comment: @UniKitty http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252738/152859

Comment: The location is retrieved with some third party tool, think Yahoo - it's likely their fault.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the report. Are you still experiencing this behavior? I'm unable to reproduce this.

Comment: @Mike [it still happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263799/we-dont-speak-russian-in-canada).

Comment: @Aurélien so any idea what might be causing this? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, it comes from the fact that the google location autocomplete on the job post form displays results according to the user's browser language. The issue is we cache those server side when we shouldn't. It's not an easy one to fix but we have it on the radar.

Comment: Thanks @Aurélien but I wonder, how it doesn't impact more people?

Comment: @ShadowWizard no idea at this point