# StackOverflow Careers: Better detailed remote locations

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

I have been looking through the SO Careers site of late and because I am located in Australia there isn't as many opportunities as there would be for people in the US; especially in the city I live in.

Because of this I attempted to look for positions that allow **remote** work, but trouble is practically none of the positions that state they allow remote work indicate how remote they will consider.

Is it..

- Remote is ok, but you must live in the same city
- Remote is ok, but you must live in the same country
- Remote is ok, but you must live in a similar timezone
- Remote is ok, anywhere in any timezone

Without any more details on what the employer will accept, searching for positions that will allow remote work is practically useless for people living outside of the US.

Comment: May I ask why this was moved to SE; I initially considered posting it here, but considering SO Careers is part of the SO domain I figured that was the place to post it no!?

Comment: Unfortunately even though that other question/request is over 2 years old it seems remote is still as unclear as ever. :(

Comment: Careers questions live here rather than on MSO. I thought that question was a pretty good indication of what 'allows remote' means but I see you're asking to improve the functionality rather than an explanation for what it is. Have removed the dupe flag.

Comment: @Brett This answers [why this was moved to SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252737/where-to-ask-careers-questions-stack-overflow-meta-or-stack-exchange-meta/252738#252738)

Comment: @DeanWard Thanks for that. :)